# Hidden airwires in Eagle ...?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have designed a PCB using Autodesk Eagle.

After I routing the PC and check for errors from Tools -> Errors, there are lot of airwires (31) like below. But, I couldn't find any airwire.

How to solve this problem?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: There's a ulp for that.  Well, a 3rd party one.

Comment: Do you have layer 19 hidden?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No. Its visible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry. I didn't get it.

Comment: Try the hints given [here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/56812/l/air-wire-problems?displayFullThread=true): rerun DRC, set the airwire colour to bright magenta, turn all layers off except the airwire layers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding air wires in Eagle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34917/finding-air-wires-in-eagle)

Comment: @Bruno .. yes.that was the ansawer. EAGLE dosen't update errors real time. Need to check manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rerunning DRC problem is solved as @Huisman mentioned.

If you just select Tools -> Errors, It shows previous errors without updating current status.

Use Tools -> DRC... and click on the Check button to update the errors.